# Automatic conversion of empty string to undef in Perl Moo objects

Tags: perl, attributes, moo

For some fields of a Perl Moo object I want to replace empty string when it is assigned to the field with `undef`.

That is I want: `$obj->x("")` to make the field `x` undefined.

Please help to develop a Moo extension which does this.

---

A possible way to do this:

```
sub make_field_undef {
  my ($class, $field_name) = @_;
  eval "package $class";
  around $field_name => sub {
    my $orig = shift;
    my $self = shift;
    my @args = @_;
    if(@args >= 1) {
      $args[0] = undef if defined $args[0] && $args[0] eq '';
    }
    $orig->($self, @args);
  };
}
```

But are there "more structured" or "more declarative" ways to do this? Any other ways to do this?

---

A complete example with my implementation of it follows. But running it produces errors which I do not understand:

```
package UndefOnEmpty;
use Moo;

sub auto_undef_fields { () }

sub make_fields_undef {
  my ($class) = @_;
  eval "package $class";
  around [$class->auto_undef_fields] => sub {
    my $orig = shift;
    my $self = shift;
    my @args = @_;
    if(@args >= 1) {
      $args[0] = undef if defined $args[0] && $args[0] eq '';
    }
    $orig->($self, @args);
  };
  around 'BUILD' => {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    foreach my $field_name ($class->auto_undef_fields) {
      $args->{$field_name} = undef if defined $args->{$field_name} && $args->{$field_name} eq "";
    }
  };
}

1;
```

Usage example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package X;
use Moo;
use lib '.';
extends 'UndefOnEmpty';
use Types::Standard qw(Str Int Maybe);
use Data::Dumper;

has 'x' => (is=>'rw', isa=>Maybe[Str]);
has 'y' => (is=>'rw', isa=>Maybe[Str]);

sub auto_undef_fields { qw(x y) }
__PACKAGE__->make_fields_undef;

my $obj = X->new(x=>"");
$obj->y("");
print Dumper $obj->x, $obj->y;
```

Here are the errors:

```
$ ./test.pl 
"my" variable $class masks earlier declaration in same scope at UndefOnEmpty.pm line 20.
"my" variable $args masks earlier declaration in same statement at UndefOnEmpty.pm line 21.
"my" variable $field_name masks earlier declaration in same statement at UndefOnEmpty.pm line 21.
"my" variable $args masks earlier declaration in same statement at UndefOnEmpty.pm line 21.
"my" variable $field_name masks earlier declaration in same statement at UndefOnEmpty.pm line 21.
syntax error at UndefOnEmpty.pm line 20, near "foreach "
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Module/Runtime.pm line 317.
```

Please help to understand what are the causes of the errors.

Comment: this is not a code-writing service. It's to help with specific code issues. Please show us what you've already got, and explain the specific problem area you're having trouble with.

Comment: I'll gladly help you, but you haven't done anything at all yet so I don't see what I can do to help.

Comment: I've added my solution attempt

Comment: So how your solutions fails to do what you want? The question 'are there "more structured" or "more declarative" ways to do this?' sounds very unclear; if you solved your issue with your code, you should either show a specific technical reason why it's not suitable for you or this becomes too broad/opinion based for SO.

Comment: I've added a complete example with my implementation. But it produces errors which I do not understand. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a coercion with the `coerce` attribute [in `has`](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/Moo#has)? That seems to be the most simple and straightforward way.

```
package Foo;
use Moo;

has bar => (
    is     => 'rw',
    coerce => sub { $_[0] eq q{} ? undef : $_[0] },
);
```

Here's what objects look like then.

```
package main;
use Data::Printer;
p my $foo1 = Foo->new( bar => q{} );
p my $foo2 = Foo->new( bar => 123 );
p my $foo3 = Foo->new;

__END__

Foo  {
    Parents       Moo::Object
    public methods (2) : bar, new
    private methods (0)
    internals: {
        bar   undef
    }
}
Foo  {
    Parents       Moo::Object
    public methods (2) : bar, new
    private methods (0)
    internals: {
        bar   123
    }
}
Foo  {
    Parents       Moo::Object
    public methods (2) : bar, new
    private methods (0)
    internals: {}
}
```

---

In Moose you can also define your own type that derives from your `Str` and has a built-in coercion. Then you can make all your attributes of that type and turn coercion on.

To make Moo behave like that, look at the documentation of `has` and the attribute `isa`, which is right above `coerce` (linked above).